# Prove that $f(x;y) = \frac{(x + y - 2)(x + y - 1)}{2} + y$ is bijection

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics

$$f(x;y) = \frac{(x + y - 2)(x + y - 1)}{2} + y$$

Need to prove that this function bijectively displays each element of the set of positive integers $\mathbb{N}$.
I haven't seen any tasks of this type just examples of bijection to $\mathbb{N}$ from $\mathbb{Q,Z}$ etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Lemma.** let $\displaystyle\varphi(n)=\left\lceil \sqrt{2n+\frac14}+\frac12\right\rceil$. Then
$$ k=\varphi(n)\quad\iff \quad\frac{(k-1)(k-2)}{2}< n\le \frac{k(k-1)}{2}$$
*Proof.*

$$\eqalign{
k=\varphi(n) \iff&\quad k-1<\sqrt{2n+\frac14}+\frac12\le k\cr
\iff&\quad \left(k-\frac32\right)^2<{2n+\frac14}\le \left(k-\frac12\right)^2\cr
\iff&\quad k^2-3k+2<{2n}\le k^2-k\cr
\iff&\quad \frac{(k-1)(k-2)}{2}< n\le \frac{k(k-1)}{2}
}$$
This proves the lemma. $\square$

Let $n$ be a positive integer, and suppose that $f(x,y)=n$ then
$$\frac{(x+y-2)(x+y-1)}{2}=n-y<n\le n+x-1=\frac{(x+y-1)(x+y)}{2}$$
So, according to the lemma, this implies that 
$x+y=\varphi(n)$ and
$$ x=1+\frac{(\varphi(n)-1)\varphi(n)}{2}-n,\quad
y=n-\frac{(\varphi(n)-2)(\varphi(n)-1)}{2}$$
And  these two numbers are  positive  integers  according  to the same lemma,  and it is  easy to check that conversely, if $x$, and $y$ are given by these formulas then $f(x,y)=n$. So,  $f$ is bijective, and we are  done.

Comment: thanks for the proof. But I didn't get how you get rid of ceiling. Could you explain a little bit more?

Comment: @ValeryBaturin, the basic property is $\lceil u\rceil = m$ if and only if $m$ is an integer and $m-1<u\le m$. This could be taken as the definition.